# Performance of a query - "difficult case"

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I have a question about structuring a query. In my select I first create a preparation "portfolio" select with relatively big data cca 2 mil rows.
In this preparation I create a case which looks at values from different columns and the result is then a used in other parts of the with clause.

Maybe better will be an example:

```
with portfolio as
(
select case when column_a like '%_V' and substr(column_b,10,1)='2' then column_b
      when column_c is not null then column_c
      when column_c is null and column_d is not null then column_d
      else column_b end as id_user,x.* from table1 x
),
group_a as
(
select * from portfolio where substr(id_user,1,1) in ('a','b','c')
),
group_b as
(
select * from portfolio where substr(id_user,1,1) in ('a','b','f')
),
group_c as
(
select * from portfolio where substr(id_user,1,1) in ('f','g','h')
),
group_d as
(
select * from portfolio where substr(id_user,1,1) in ('d','f','h')
)
select * from ....
```

So my question is - is it better to limit substr(id_user,1,1) in the portfolio definition if I know it will be only in ('a','b','c','d','f','g','h')?

I dont know much about SQL query plans, but my reasoning was that if I use some other conditions on the portfolio rows I extract in group subselects (which I use I just did not put them in the example)then the program will not have to go through all the values of user_id and it will save some time against the option of running the substring in the whole portfolio in the first place.

In the script I use other parts of the id_user (other substrings) so I want the whole user_id to be the output od portfolio.

Thank you I hope it is clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Are a,b, and c columns in table1? It's confusing because later they are characters 'a', 'b', 'c'.

Comment: Oh sorry that got there by mistake. I use Oracle

Comment: You might change your case statement to: case when a like '%_V' and substr(b,10,1)='2' then b else coalesce(c,d,b) end

Comment: You might also project the definition substr(id_user,1,1) from your first CTE so you can simplify the later CTEs.

Comment: @DavidAldridge The coalesce is very handy, thank you for that advice. About already defining the substr in the first CTE - I will have to make a substr out of the whole case right? Or do you mean create one extra CTE with all my substrings I use? I use substr on user_id together for (1,9), (1,6), (10,1), and (7,3) where those numbers in brackets are the values in substr. Should I make one CTE which converts this from the portfolio?

Comment: @EmilHolub I would structure it so that if substr(user_id,1,9) gives you a particular value that you need to access multiple times, then try to express it once and give the value a meaningful alias. It might not end up benefiting performance (noticeably) but would be a great aid to maintainability. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: @DavidAldridge Thank you, I will restructure it a bit. This was already a not very beautiful piece of code I "bequeathed" from someone else - it was structured as unions where the portfolio data was in every one of those, I restructered it to the CTE and the run time is already down from 60 to 6 minutes. I was just curious to learn some other techniques how to improve performance :)